# Smali Unsigned short value out of range

Tags: smali

```
> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: org.jf.util.ExceptionWithContext:
> Unsigned short value out of range: 92519  at
> org.jf.dexlib2.writer.DexDataWriter.writeUshort(DexDataWriter.java:116)
>   at
> org.jf.dexlib2.writer.InstructionWriter.write(InstructionWriter.java:315)
>   at org.jf.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeCodeItem(DexWriter.java:997)
>   at
> org.jf.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeDebugAndCodeItems(DexWriter.java:773)
>   at org.jf.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeTo(DexWriter.java:222)  at
> org.jf.dexlib2.writer.DexWriter.writeTo(DexWriter.java:200)   at
> org.jf.smali.main.main(main.java:235)
```

So I am reverse engineering a big game's `classes.dex`.
I changed it to `smali`s and edited it.
Now I want to convert it back to dex file but it says there are too many methods so I will not do that!
Is there an alternative way to convert it back to dex?

Comment: Are you trying to combine the classes from multiple dex files or something? (classes.dex, classes2.dex, etc.)

Comment: @JesusFreke No, just "a" file

Comment: What kind of edits did you do? Does it recompile if you don't change anything?

Answer (score 0):

i got the similar error while using apktool. when building the modified apk.

error occures when i add new file or method to classes.dex smali files.

try to add new file in last classes.dex (multi dex).

sorry for bad english